# How do I turn off "warnings treated as error" in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a project in development that I need to test, but it won't compile because I have unreferenced variables and the option is enabled to turn all warnings into errors.  I have googled it and see that there is supposed to be a build page that I cannot find.  Help where do I turn this off?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

It would appear that for VS 2008 Pro The option is in Project»Properties»Configuration Properties»C/C++»General.  As shown in the image.

[image: Project»Properties»Configuration Properties»C/C++»General]

Answer (score 1):

Right click your root project folder in Solution Explorer and select 'Properties'.
This should open with a bunch of horizontal tabs on the left. Click the 'Build' tab and look for the sub section labeled "Treat warnings as errors".  You will probably see that the 'All' option is selected and this is what is causing your warnings to be treated as errors.

Note that this usually happens under the 'Release' profile which is more strict by default about errors than say 'Debug'.